# How to render html from a @foreach loop in a textarea

Tags: php, html, arrays, laravel, laravel-livewire

Using Laravel 8 livewire, I need to render a list of name ($list) on per line in a textarea.
I do this

```
<div class=" border border-red-800 rounded-lg mt-8 p-4 w-full bg-green-300">
    <form>

        <textarea rows="10"  class="w-full bg-yellow-100">
        
            @foreach ($list as $maltproducer)
                {{$maltproducer->name}}
            @endforeach

        </textarea>
        <x-input.group label="Producer" for='name' :error="$errors->first('name')"
            class="flex flex-col w-full p-2 border border-jbrown-peachpuf bg-jbrown-darker rounded-md ">
            <x-input.text wire:model="name" type="text" class="" name="name" id="name" value="" />
        </x-input.group>
        <button wire:click.prevent="store()" class="bg-red-400 px-2 py-1 border rounded-lg mt-2">Add this
            producer</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The name are displayed one per line but they are not at the beginning of the line. To have them at the beginning of the line, I have to move my source code to the beginning of the line as here below.

```
@foreach ($list as $maltproducer) 
{{$maltproducer->name}} 
@endforeach
```

This is not acceptable as the file could be formatted differently by the code editor without me even be aware of it.
I tried various thing such as

```
@foreach ($list as $maltproducer)
  <p>{{$maltproducer->name}}</p>
@endforeach
```

but in this case the `<p>` markup is displayed but not interpreted.

I also tried `{!!$maltproducer->name!!}`, `{!!<p>$maltproducer->name</p>!!}` etc. but I could never manage to get the good result i.e to have one name per line at the beginning of the line.

What is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

A textarea renders everything between its tags as the value - this includes spaces, tabs and newlines. So you want to print each line without any spaces before or after the actual value you want. To best accomplish this, is to print the output without any "pretty" format in your code.

We can achieve that by *plucking* the field from the collection you want to print, then implode that with a newline as the glue. In PHP, that would look like

```php
implode("\n", $list->pluck('name'))
```

Then its just a matter of printing that directly between the textarea, without any spacing or newlines.

```
<textarea rows="10" class="w-full bg-yellow-100">{{ implode("\n", $list->pluck('name')) }}</textarea>
```

Even more Laravel-ish, using the `implode()` method on the collection directly,

```
<textarea rows="10" class="w-full bg-yellow-100">{{ $list->implode('name', "\n") }}</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I have an error with implode : ErrorException
implode(): Invalid arguments passed (View: /ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL/EASYBEER/resources/views/livewire/malt/producer-lw.blade.php) (View: /ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL/EASYBEER/resources/views/livewire/malt/producer-lw.blade.php)  if I only use $list->pluck('name') i got an array ['name1',"name2",....,"nameX"] which is correct, thus I don't understand where the error comes from.

Comment: Hmm.. What is `dd($list->pluck('name'));`? What type is it, and is it just a 1-dimentional array with a bunch of names?

Comment: You can alternatively just use `{{ $list->implode('name', "\n") }}`, give that a try

Comment: With the last proposal only the first line has leading spaces.  Here is the output of dd($list->pluck('name') : Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#435 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Malt\Producer {#436 ▶}
    1 => App\Models\Malt\Producer {#437 ▶}
    2 => App\Models\Malt\Producer {#438 ▶}
  ]
}  Please see EDIT###################### in the original post

Comment: `$list->implode('name', "\n")` should work just fine on its own. But as I said in my answer, you shouldn't have any spaces or newlines between the `<textarea>` tags. It needs to be exactly the snipped I posted above, not formatted with newlines.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but please don't waste to much of your time as I can do what I want with a div and paragraphs inside.